# get all words from string with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need `preg_match` that can find me all words from string.
for example:

```
$str = "string: hi, it is string.";
```

I would like get this:

```
[0] => string
[1] => hi
[2] => it
[3] => is
[4] => string
```

I use with `'/[a-z]+/ui'`, but I get this:

```
[0] => string:
[1] => hi,
[2] => it
[3] => is
[4] => string.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `preg_match()`, instead you should be using [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and there is no need to use the `u` modifier in your regular expression here.

```
$str = "string: hi, it is string.";

preg_match_all('/[a-z]+/i', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => string
    [1] => hi
    [2] => it
    [3] => is
    [4] => string
)
```